# Rails: Validating min and max length of a string but allowing it to be blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, model

I have a field that I would like to validate. I want the field to be able to be left blank, but if a user is entering data I want it to be in a certain format. Currently I am using the below validations in the model, but this doesn't allow the user to leave it blank:

```
validates_length_of :foo, :maximum => 5
validates_length_of :foo, :minimum => 5
```

How do I write this to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 151, accepted):

I think it might need something like:

```
validates_length_of :foo, minimum: 5, maximum: 5, allow_blank: true
```

More examples: [ActiveRecord::Validations::ClassMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: for a specific size you can use the lenght constraint :is

Answer (score 163):

You can also use this format:

```
validates :foo, length: {minimum: 5, maximum: 5}, allow_blank: true
```

Or since your min and max are the same, the following will also work:

```
validates :foo, length: {is: 5}, allow_blank: true
```

Answer (score 17):

Or even more concise (with the new hash syntax), from the [validates documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates):

```
validates :foo, length: 5..5, allow_blank: true
```

The upper limit should probably represent somehting more meaningful like "in: 5..20", but just answering the question to the letter.

Comment: In don't think `in` will work with strings, seems to be numbers only

Comment: This should work instead `validates :foo, length: 2..5, allow_blank: true` but ` length: { is: 5}` would do in the OP's case

Answer (score 13):

From the [validates_length_of documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_length_of):

```
validates_length_of :phone, :in => 7..32, :allow_blank => true
```

> `:allow_blank` - Attribute may be blank; skip validation.

Answer (score 3):

every validates_* accepts :if or :unless options

```
validates_length_of :foo, :maximum => 5, :if => :validate_foo_condition
```

where validate_foo_condition is method that returns true or false

you can also pass a Proc object:

```
validates_length_of :foo, :maximum => 5, :unless => Proc.new {|object| object.foo.blank?}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about that:
`validates_length_of :foo, is: 3, allow_blank: true`

Answer (score 2):

```
validates_length_of :reason, minimum: 3, maximum: 30
```

rspec for the same is

```
it { should validate_length_of(:reason).is_at_least(3).is_at_most(30) }
```

Answer (score -1):

Add in your model:

```
validates :color, length: { is: 7 }
```

color is a string:

```
t.string :color, null: false, default: '#0093FF', limit: 7
```

Answer (score -4):

In your model e.g.

```
def validate
  errors.add_to_base 'error message' unless self.foo.length == 5 or self.foo.blanc?
end
```