# update_attributes on other attributes causes password validation error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to use update_attributes to update my user object, but even though I don't pass in a password attribute in the params I send to update_attributes, I still get the password blank error.

I have two pages, one for updating user info except password and one for just updating password.  How do I force the password validations to trigger on blank/nil on one form, but not the other?

```
validates :password, length: {minimum: 8}, format: {with: VALID_PASSWORD_REGEX}
```

Comment: Can you post your model validations?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried restricting your presence validation to the `create` action?

```
validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
validates             :password,
                      :length => {
                        :minimum => 8
                      },
                      :format => {
                        :with => VALID_PASSWORD_REGEX
                      },
                      :allow_blank => true
```

Comment: I also need to validate passwords when a user changes it

Comment: Yup, that's only skipping the presence validation. All others would still apply.

Comment: but in the case the user doesn't put anything when changing, presence is needed to catch that right? Also, I have a length and a regex that would give me an error on a blank/nil password, right?

Comment: That's where you use `:allow_blank => true`, for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441882/validating-min-and-max-length-of-a-string-but-allowing-it-to-be-blank

Comment: Edited my question to include the other validations.

Comment: I don't want the password update form to be good when the user updates with blank new passwords. This causes the form to go through on password update with blank password fields.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "updates with blank new passwords". If the user doesn't fill up the password field, it doesn't even gets included in the params.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39536/discussion-between-depa-and-derek)

Comment: right, the user.valid? should equal false when a user updates with blank passwords. But these validations cause user.valid? to be true.